# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number al usar un bundle en Java

Tags: java, archivo-de-propiedades

Para limpiar mi código decidí extraer mis cadenas a un archivo `properties`.

El problema es que ahora me dan un error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number:
>
> ```
> Matcher m = Pattern.compile(\"{0}\").matcher(\"{1}\");
> int groupsNum = m.groupCount();    while (m.find()) {
>    for (int i = 1; i <= groupsNum; i++) {
>        try {
>            String group = m.group(i);
>            allGroups.add(group);
>        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
>            allGroups.add(\"No Matches\");
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1429)

Más abajo en la traza me sale la causa

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:  "
>
> ```
> Matcher m = Pattern.compile(\"{0}\").matcher(\"{1}\");    int
> groupsNum = m.groupCount();    while (m.find()) {
>        for (int i = 1; i <= groupsNum; i++) {
>            try {
>                String group = m.group(i);
>                allGroups.add(group);
>            } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
>                allGroups.add(\"No Matches\");
>            }
>        }    } "
> ```
>
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Cargo la cadena de esta manera

```
private static String generateJavaSearchingCode(String regexText, String testCase) {
        return MessageFormat.format(
                java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("codegeneration").getString("JAVA_SEARCHING")
                , escapedRegexText(regexText), escapedRegexText(testCase));
 }
```

En mi properties tengo la cadena de esta manera:

```
JAVA_SEARCHING=List<String> allGroups = new ArrayList<>();\ntry {\n   Matcher m = Pattern.compile(\\"{0}\\").matcher(\\"{1}\\");\n   int groupsNum = m.groupCount();\n   while (m.find()) {\n       for (int i = 1; i <= groupsNum; i++) {\n           try {\n               String group = m.group(i);\n               allGroups.add(group);\n           } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {\n               allGroups.add(\\"No Matches\\");\n           }\n       }\n   }\n} catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {\n   allGroups.add(pse.getMessage());\n}
```

Originalmente la cargaba como:

```
private static String generateJavaSearchingCode(String regexText, String testCase) {
  return new StringBuilder("val allGroups = ArrayList()\n")
                .append("try {\n")
                .append("    val m = Pattern.compile(\"")
                .append(escapedRegexText(regexText))
                .append("\").matcher(\"")
                .append(escapedRegexText(testCase))
                .append("\")\n")
                .append("   val groupsNum = m.groupCount()\n")
                .append("   while (m.find()) {\n")
                .append("       for (i in 1..groupsNum) {\n")
                .append("           try {\n")
                .append("               val group = m.group(i)\n")
                .append("               allGroups.add(group)\n")
                .append("           } catch (ise:IllegalStateException) {\n")
                .append("               allGroups.add(\"No Matches\")\n")
                .append("           }\n")
                .append("       }\n")
                .append("   }\n")
                .append("} catch (pse:PatternSyntaxException) {\n")
                .append("   allGroups.add(pse.getMessage())\n")
                .append("}")
                .toString();
}
```

Y nunca me dió ese tipo de problemas.

Se me hace muy curioso porque el refactor funcionó perfeto en otras cadenas, por ejemplo

```
JAVA_SPLIT=Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(\\"{0}\\");\nString[] splitted= pattern.split(\\"{1}\\",0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hallé la [solución en la contraparte gringa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625189/6999690), el problema es que en los archivos `.properties` se deben de escapar los corchetes usando comillas simples cuando se quiera usar el remplazo dinámico de parámetros

así:

```
JAVA_SEARCHING=List<String> allGroups = new ArrayList<>();\ntry '{'\n   Matcher m = Pattern.compile(\\"{0}\\").matcher(\\"{1}\\");\n   int groupsNum = m.groupCount();\n   while (m.find()) '{'\n       for (int i = 1; i <= groupsNum; i++) '{'\n           try '{'\n               String group = m.group(i);\n               allGroups.add(group);\n           '}' catch (IllegalStateException ise) '{'\n               allGroups.add(\\"No Matches\\");\n           '}'\n       '}'\n   '}'\n'}' catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) '{'\n   allGroups.add(pse.getMessage());\n'}'
```